# Git remove large binary from history - but keep the tags

Tags: git, tags, binary, history

This has been posted many times on Stack Overflow, but none of the answers include what to do if you have tags.

My problem is that I cleared out a binary file from every branch using

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm -rf --ignore-unmatch audio_samples' HEAD
```

This seemed to work nicely but my repository wasn't getting any smaller! Even when I tried

```
git clone file:///path/to/project1 project1clone
```

It was still the same size.

It was only when I checked out a tag, I realized the binary file was still being referenced. OK, so I removed all my tags, and now a new cloned repo is smaller. However, I need my tags, so I reverted to a backed up version of my project directory, and am now back at square one. How do make it so that my tags aren't referencing a commit with the large binary file, but still pointing to where they should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command there is only rewriting `HEAD`. Try using `-- --all` instead of `HEAD`.